quid vs. quod difference
as far as I understand, quid is an interrogative pronoun but seemingly both quid (/quis) and quod (/quí) are relative pronouns. Do I understand that right? Why do I find so many examples of "quid" in non-interrogative (i. e. relative) contexts? Is this a colloquialism?

The obvious question: can you provide examples?

Are you sure you didn’t mean to ask about the use of qui, quae and quod as interrogative rather than relative forms? That is an established use (mostly as adjectives, although qui also appears not too rarely as an interrogative pronoun), whereas I can’t understand where you’d see quid used as a relative form.

Note that there’s a difference between relative clauses and indirect question clauses (e.g. “Quid ipse sentiam expōnam” uses quid in an indirect question).

Example taken from Allen and Greenough here: https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/indirect-questions

@Asteroides: Good idea, that is probably what's behind this.
